# Proper way to roundtrip record field declarations

Tags: haskell, record, template-haskell

Suppose you're writing some Template Haskell code that transforms record declarations. The first transformation you would want to write is the identity one, right? So let's go over the fields and not change them:

```
module TH where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

foo :: DecsQ -> DecsQ
foo = fmap $ map $ \d -> case d of
    DataD _ dataName tvbs Nothing [con@(RecC conName fields)] [] ->
        DataD [] dataName
          tvbs
          Nothing
          [RecC conName $ map transformField fields]
          []
    _ -> d

-- TODO: Write my awesome transformation here
transformField :: VarBangType -> VarBangType
transformField (v, b, t) = (v, b, t)
```

You try it out in a module with a record type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import TH

foo [d| data R = MkR{ x :: Int } |]
```

So far so good. However, things break if we turn on `DuplicateRecordFields` in our program, even though we haven't written `transformField` yet (i.e. it is still the identity function):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
import TH

foo [d| data R = MkR{ x :: Int } |]
```

This program now fails to compile, with the following message:

> Use.hs:5:1: error:
>
> Illegal variable name: `$sel:x:MkR`
>
> When splicing a TH declaration:
>
> ```
> data R_0 = MkR_1 {$sel:x:MkR_2 :: GHC.Types.Int}
> ```

Even this super-minimal program fails with a similar error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields, TemplateHaskell #-}

$([d| data R = MkR{ x :: Int } |])
```

There's not much mystery **why** this happens: [as the `DuplicateRecordFields` documentation explains](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/records/overloaded-record-fields/duplicate-record-fields#mangling-selector-names), field selectors are mangled to be unique accross all record types, and TH gets these mangled field names.

But **how to solve this** is not explained on that same page. For now, I am using the following function to unmangle a mangled field name into something that roundtrips accross data declaration splices:

```
import Data.List.Split

unmangle :: Name -> Name
unmangle (Name occ flavour) = Name occ' flavour
  where
    occ' = case wordsBy (== ':') (occString occ) of
        ["$sel", fd, _qual] -> mkOccName fd
        _ -> occ

transformField :: VarBangType -> VarBangType
transformField (v, b, t) = (unmangle v, b, t)
```

This works, but doesn't feel like the right solution, and probably won't survive changes to GHC-internal details of name mangling. Is there a better way to do this?